# Get number of pages of a xlxs document like when printing

Tags: c#, xlsx

How I can get number of pages of a xlxs document like when printing. I`m using C# and can calculate number of worksheets but not a print pages.

**Update:** As input I have only file stream.

Comment: which library are you using?

Comment: have you tried to use ```ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count``` ?

Comment: Could you share some more? 
Relevant code, libraries and frameworks you are using, ..

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example this really helps to get to the point of your question!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Windows application, you can use WMI-class Win32_printjob, see [the ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printjob)
You will need the property "TotalPages", something like this:

```
       ManagementObjectSearcher findJobs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT TotalPages FROM Win32_PrintJob");
       ManagementObjectCollection  foundJobs = findJobs ();
       foreach (var job in foundJobs )
       {        
         string Totalpages = prntJob.Properties["TotalPages"].Value.ToString();
       }
```

You probably want more properties than just "TotalJobs" to see which job is the one you are looking for.  But this should give you a starting point!